# css hover over keep menu display block

Tags: html, css

I have created a notification system using html and css (please see below) but when i hover over the icon the menu appears which is correct, but when i move to choose any of the icons it disappears. Although i am not technically hovering over it because there is a small gap is there any way to fix this little delay?

```css
.numberCircle {
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}

       .showme {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 153px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:#1D1E22;
  border: 3px solid white;
  text-align:center !important;

}
 .Resources:hover .showme {display: block;}

.Resources:hover ~ .showme {
display:block;

}
.showme:hover{
    display:block;

}

.Resources:hover .showme {
  display: block;
}

.showme {
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #719ECE;  /*set border colour here*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8)); /*set shadow colour  and size here*/
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8));
}

.showme:after,
.showme:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.showme:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -19px;
}

.showme:before {
  border-color: rgba(113, 158, 206, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #719ECE;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Resources" style=" width: 60px; height: 70px; float:left;margin-top:30px">
    <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
    <div id="ctl00_TopMenu_FontAwesome_divFA">
    
<i class="fa fa-fw  fa-bell fa-3x " aria-hidden="true" style="   color:black;padding-top:10px;"  ></i>

</div>



<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
    
</div>

<div class="showme" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-190px;margin-top:80px;text-align:center;padding:20px;">  
            <a href="../../Brands.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A1" style="width:150px">Brands</a>
            <hr />
            <a href="../../StockImages.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A2" style="width:150px">Stock Images</a>
            <hr />
            <a href="../../HowTo.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A3" style="width:150px">How-To's</a>
            <hr />
        </div>
```

Comment: Use padding-top on the `showme` element instead of margin-top. Margin doesn't count as part of the element for hovering purposes, creating that gap.

Comment: A better way to have this working is to have `.showme` as a child of `.Resources`. This will resolve your problem with the added benefit of grouping your icon with its menu. However, switching to padding vs margin (as mentioned before) will solve the problem.

Note - making the menu a child of `Resources` will require some css refactoring, notably making `Resources` a relative position and `showme` absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML code, add line-height to the "Resources" style i.e

```
<div class="Resources" style=" width: 60px; height: 70px; float:left;margin-top:30px; line-height: 70px;">
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nehasharma_/tsu4y0wv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need an overlap in order for the `:hover` to continue to work. I recommend wrapping `.showme` with a `div` which it's purpose is to complete the overlap and `.showme` remains for visual purpose.

```
.showme-wrap {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-190px;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
.numberCircle {
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
}

.showme {
  width: 153px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color:#1D1E22;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center !important;
}

.Resources:hover .showme-wrap {
  display:block;
}

.showme-wrap {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-190px;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.showme:hover{
  display:block;
}

.Resources:hover .showme {
  display: block;
}

.showme {
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #719ECE;  /*set border colour here*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8)); /*set shadow colour  and size here*/
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113, 158, 206, 0.8));
}

.showme:after,
.showme:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.showme:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -19px;
}

.showme:before {
  border-color: rgba(113, 158, 206, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #719ECE;
  border-width: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>

<div class="Resources" style="width: 60px; height: 70px; float:left;margin-top:30px">
  <div class="numberCircle">1</div>
  <div id="ctl00_TopMenu_FontAwesome_divFA">
    <i class="fa fa-fw  fa-bell fa-3x " aria-hidden="true" style="color:black;padding-top:10px;"></i>
  </div>
  
  <div class="showme-wrap">
    <div class="showme" style="">  
        <a href="../../Brands.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A1" style="width:150px">Brands</a>
        <hr />
        <a href="../../StockImages.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A2" style="width:150px">Stock Images</a>
        <hr />
        <a href="../../HowTo.aspx" id="ctl00_TopMenu_A3" style="width:150px">How-To's</a>
        <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```